# Retrieving data from WPF Datagrid into a List does not have the same number of columns

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I have a question, although I have searched here a lot but not have answer.
I have 2 class

```
class adminApp
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Email { get; set; }
   public string Password { get; set; }
   public string FullName { get; set; }
   public Nullable<System.DateTime> StartFrom { get; set; }
   public string LicenseKey { get; set; }
   public bool Checked { get; set; }
}

class User
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string FullName { get; set; }
   public string Email { get; set; }
   public Nullable<System.DateTime> StartFrom { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using Web API to get from MSSQL and push to adminApp class after that load up to Gridview. I write an update function need only send ID, FullName, Email, StratFrom to API. I try to write a Linq to get data from Gridview but it still null. Please help me correcrt my code:

```
List<User> list = dgvList.Items
                         .OfType<User>()
                         .Where(x => x.Checked == true)
                         .ToList();
```

Comment: You said you are loading `adminApp`s, not `User`s so why are you trying to pull `User`s?

Comment: Ya i want to send "PUT" to my API to update. I only accept edit Name, Email, Startfrom. I dont want send all data to Server because security or just want minimize the data sent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question lacks enough context to be sure, but if your grid is full of `addminApps` then you cannot pull `User` directly back out. Try this which performs a projection into a list of `User`:

```
List<User> list = dgvList.Items
                 .OfType<adminApp>()
                 .Where(x => x.Checked == true)
                 .Select(a => new User{ 
                     Id = a.Id, 
                     FullName = a.FullName, 
                     Email = a.Email, 
                     StartFrom = a.StartFrom })
                 .ToList();
```